# Remove one of the links outputted from `which` command

Tags: linux, bash, macos

I have jupyter installed in two places (correct me if this understanding is wrong).

```sh
$ which -a jupyter
/Users/ricky/Library/Python/3.7/bin/jupyter
/usr/local/bin/jupyter
```

I only want to keep `/usr/local/bin/jupyter` and remove the other one. How would I go about this on Mac OS Big Sur running Bash?

Comment: Edit the `PATH` environment variable in your shell initialization file.

Comment: Either edit your PATH or remove the executable bit from the other jupyter.

Comment: Don't use `which`, use `type`.

Comment: Editing the `PATH` environment variable fixed it @Barmar! But what's the difference between `which` and `type`? The output looks basically the same

Comment: @RickyPalaguachi, try `which cd`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then

Answer (score 0):

From @Barmar's comment...

I needed to edit my `PATH` environment variable to remove the reference to `/Users/ricky/Library/Python/3.7/bin/jupyter`.